MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/products/
I'm encountering a MultiValueDictKeyError in my Django project when trying to access the API at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/. The error occurs on this line: category = self.request.GET['category'].
Here is my view:
class ProductList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProductListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        category = self.request.GET['category']
        category = models.Product.objects.get(category)
        qs = qs.filter(category=category)
        return qs

My Product model is defined as follows:
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='product_in_category')
    retailer = models.ForeignKey(Retailer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

Here is my serializer:
class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    productreview = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
        fields = ['id', 'category', 'retailer', 'title', 'detail', 'price', 'productreview']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductListSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

I am trying to call a list of products according to the product category from my React frontend, but I keep encountering the MultiValueDictKeyError. I tried using GET.get and various other approaches but haven't been able to resolve the issue.
Here is the error traceback:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/
Django Version: 4.2.13
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value: 'category'

How can I fix this error and properly filter the products by category?


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/

Django Version: 4.2.13
Python Version: 3.11.9
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'corsheaders',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework_simplejwt',
 'ecommerce']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 84, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

During handling of the above exception ('category'), another exception occurred:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/shital/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/shital/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/shital/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
    ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/shital/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/shital/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 243, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/shital/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 38, in list
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/shital/ecommerce/ecom/ecommerce/views.py", line 19, in get_queryset
    category = self.request.GET['category']
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 86, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/products/
Exception Value: 'category'


Well you did not include the category in the URL, hence that will not work.

self.request.GET['category'] This expects category to be present in the url as a query string, i.e. something like http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/?category=food.

Django looks for category in the querystring, and there is none, so that is the problem. You should visit it with:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/?category=14
But that will still not work: you should filter with the category, so:
class ProductList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProductListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        category = self.request.GET['category']
        return super().get_queryset().filter(category_id=category)
This will thus obtain the Products with a category with pk=14.

I did tired this one still got same error i did even use query_params , am still wondering where did i miss that am still stuck

Can you share the full traceback? Are you sure you are triggering the correct view endpoint?

thank you for the help, i provided on the question box

@Shital: but it says the request URL is Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/, not with ?category=...?

yess am just trying to fetch  all the products list according to the category
on my react

@Shital: well then the react should add the category to the querystring.

Thank you for the help will update if faced anything regarding this. Am just a beginner so got more to learn.
